# Ordered list level from XML in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, document

i need to convert this xml in the following (just like numbered order list in Microsoft World), i am using Java Langauage
Please need some solution to convert the XML in to the level xml

```
<RECORDS name="Record1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <RECORD name="Record 1.1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" required="Y">
        <field name="1.1.1unitPrice" type="string" maxlength="10"  required="Y" />
        <field name="1.1.2amount" type="date"   required="N" />
        <field name="prc" type="1.1.3double"  required="N" />
        <field name="salvage" type="double"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" required="N" />
        <field name="sum" type="string"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" required="Y" />
               <RECORD name="1.1.5.1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" required="Y">
                   <field name="1.1.5.1.1" type="string" maxlength="10"  required="Y" />
                   <field name="1.1.5.1.2" type="date"  m required="N" />

               </RECORD>
    </RECORD>
       <RECORD name="1.2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" required="Y">
        <field name="unitPrice" type="string" maxlength="10"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" required="Y" />
    </RECORD>
    <field name="1.3price" type="string" maxlength="10"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    <field name="1.4amount" type="date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" required="N" />

</RECORDS>
```

The Above is source XML. this should be converted into the following XML using JAVA. is there any Solution please help me out.
..............................

```
<Records>
<line>
<level>1</level>
<name>Record1</name>
</line>

<line>
<level>1.1</level>
<name>Record 1.1</name>
</line>

<line>
<level>1.1.1</level>
<name>1.1.1unitPrice</name>
</line>

<line>
<level>1.1.2</level>
<name>1.1.2amount</name>
</line>
.
.
.
.
<line>
<level>1.3</level>
<name>price</name>
</line>

<line>
<level>1.4</level>
<name>amount</name>
</line>


</Records>
```

Comment: Sure there is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: i am unable to find the level in the given format

Comment: private static void printNode(NodeList nodeList, int level) {
 level++;
 if (nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0) {

   for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

  Node node = nodeList.item(i);
  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

   System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + "[" + level + "]");
   printNode(node.getChildNodes(), level);

   // how depth is it?
   if (level > depthOfXML) {
    depthOfXML = level;
   }

   }

     }

   }

Comment: Please [edit] your question and incude the code there.

Comment: seems you are defining level programmatically as there is not such field level in the given xml

Answer (score 0):

You can create to types of classes, one representing the XML you have to read, and one representing the one you have to write.
You read the XML in a list of the Read-classes, and convert these classes to the Write-classes.

And then you are done.

It is al very basic standard Java XML processing, it should not be to difficult.
Read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/